# How to make svgxuse.js work with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg, turbolinks

I have just spend half of a day trying to figure it out why my **SVG sprite won't load in Internet explorer after clicking turbolink**.

As you probably know, you need some javascript to render the SVGs in IE, I use **svgxuse.js** (packed with Icomoons svg sprite).

So, if you are facing similiar issue with turbolinks and svgxuse.js you have to edit only two lines in svgxuse.js file. Just scroll to the end of the file and find:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function winLoad() {
    window.removeEventListener('load', winLoad, false); // to prevent memory leaks
    tid = setTimeout(checkUseElems, 0);
}, false);
```

And change this to:

```
window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function winLoad() {
    window.removeEventListener('turbolinks:load', winLoad, false); // to prevent memory leaks
    tid = setTimeout(checkUseElems, 0);
}, false);
```

**I have just wanted to share my "discovery" as I haven't found anything about it on Google.**

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work with svgxuse, I ended up using svg4everybody with

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", svg4everybody);
```